# Magento 2 PWA Update <title> in custom component

Tags: pwa, magento2.3.5, pwa-studio, react

How to update the title tag in the Head ?

[image]

Really don't want to mess around with the DOM updating with javascript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update `<title>` tag in custom component:

`import { Meta, Title } from 'location-to-head-component/lib/components/Head'`;

Then return:

```
return (
        <>
            <Title>you-title-here - {yourVar}</Title>
            //page content here
        </>
    );
```

OR:

```
useEffect(() => {
      document.title = 'you-title-here - '+yourVar;
   }, [title]);
```